# Is there a limit on number of Recommendations in Personalization Builder Web-Recommendations

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

In the Web Recommendations I am getting up to 5 products when I use the number of range to set a number of items, but In case of more than 5, I don't get the items on the Preview and the Webpage.
My Webpage and Catalog has a total of 10 products
Is there a limit on number of Recommendations in Personalization Builder Web-Recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

Watch exactly how your scenario order is placed. Each scenario has a limit of 100 elements. But the scenarios do not always include all elements of your product catalog. When you would include the scenario "bought bought" and there has never been a purchase this scenariolist would be empty.

Maybe you need to pay closer attention to your scenarios you have defined and if really 10 elements are in there.

Another possibility is that you have defined that exclude the other products from being inserted in the scenarios.